# i am unable to insert data into my database using php

Tags: php, insert

I am trying to insert data into my database table using php. but I am facing this error:

> Error: INSERT INTO `vacancies` (name,description,location,salary) VALUES ('','','',)
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
>   can anybody help me out...
>   here is my code as well

```
<?php

@include('dbh.php');
if(!(empty($_POST))){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $description = $_POST['content'];
  $location = $_POST['location'];
  $salary = $_POST['salary'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `vacancies` (name,description,location,salary) VALUES ('$name','$description','$location',$salary)";
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

}

?>
```

Comment: As you can see from error - `$salary` is __empty__. (Although other fields are empty too)

Comment: Did you try dumping your 4 _POST variable to see if they were set ? looking at the error it seems like they are empty

Comment: yeah u_mulder is right, you should put it inside ' ' as well

Comment: Google “sql injection” and read everything you find until you understand why your code is so dangerously vulnerable

Comment: Quotes are not the problem, we can see in the error that they are here, just empty value for each of them and especially Salary which make it crash because ,) is not acceptable in a query

Comment: @DylanKas But are you sure that `mysqli` isn't smart enough to marshall a `NULL` value of `$salary` into a MySQL `NULL`?